# Tmux conditional color setting

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to set window color depends on the other window-option?

When a windows has `synchronize-panes` enabled, I don't want to accidentally press `C-d`, or all panes will be closed.

So what I'm trying to do is to change window color on statusline based on `synchronize-panes`:
(the following config doesn't work, though)

```
bind-key S setw synchronize-panes \; \  # toggles the option
           set -w window-status-bg '#{?pane_synchronized,yellow,default}' \; \  # error: bad color
           set -w window-status-current-fg '#{?pane_synchronized,yellow,default}'  # error: bad color
```

The most possible solution I can thought of is to use `if-shell`, but I prefer not to fork a shell just to read option of itself, if possible.

---

EDIT: This `if-shell` solution works for me on tmux 2.7

My statusline cyan colored, if `synchronize-panes` is enabled, cyan becomes yellow.

```
bind-key S setw synchronize-panes \; \
           if-shell '[ #{pane_synchronized} -eq 1 ]' \
               'set -w window-status-style fg=black,bg=yellow ; set -w window-status-current-style fg=yellow,bg=black' \
               'set -w window-status-style fg=black,bg=cyan ; set -w window-status-current-style fg=cyan,bg=black'
```

---

EDIT: Problem solved, my setting is now changed to this:

```
bind-key S setw synchronize-panes

sync_ind_colour="#{?pane_synchronized,yellow,cyan}"
set -g window-status-format "#[fg=black,bg=${sync_ind_colour}][#I#{?#{!=:#W,},:,}#W]"
set -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=${sync_ind_colour},bg=black][#I#{?#{!=:#W,},:,}#W]"
```

Looks a little bit scary but it's still readable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to use `if-shell` for this.  You can use conditionals in format options, but not in styles.  The following minimal configuration should do what you want.

```
# toggle pane synchronisation mode
bind-key S setw synchronize-panes

# Variables
sync_ind_colour="#{?pane_synchronized,yellow,cyan}"

# status format
setw -g window-status-format "#[fg=black,bg=${sync_ind_colour}]#I #W"
setw -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=${sync_ind_colour},bg=black][#I #W]"
```

Note that I set the text of the window status to `#I #W` (and `[#I #W]` for active) as an example, but that's irrelevant to the question.

It's also not necessary to use a variable (`sync_ind_colour`, synchronise indicator colour), but it's simpler than defining the same conditional in both the window-status-format and the window-status-current-format variables.

Comment: OMG that's great

Comment: Is it possible to change the entire status bar colour like this? There doesn't seem to be a status-format, and the conditional doesn't seem to work for status-style. Maybe I have to set each x-status-format field separately?

Comment: Okay so it looks like the parts that support being given a format are status-left, status-right, window-status-format and window-status-current-format and I've set all of them, it almost work but I can't get the gap between the window list and the status-right. I can't seen any way to get this working.